# How to access a static member through a Class object

Tags: java

I'd like to access a static HashMap object on one of my classes. This psuedocode illustrates how I'm attempting to go about it.

```
public Class A
{
 public static HashMap<String,String> myMap;
 static
 {
  myMap.put("my key", "my value");
 }
}
...
public void myfunction(Class clazz)
{
 HashMap<String,String> myMap = clazz.getThatStaticMap();
}
...
myFunction(A.getClass());
```

The call to `getThatStaticMap()` is the part I don't know how to do.

In my actual code, I'm calling `myfunction` with a class as a parameter and returning an  `ArrayList` of objects created using the class's newInstance() method but I want access to that static data belonging to the class to configure each instance.

Comment: A is not available to me, just the Class object clazz. I should also mention (to complicate matters) that I'm using a superclass to store the instantiated objects (ArrayList<B>) so the B superclass doesn't seem to know which static members A (or any other subclass) has.

Comment: It sounds to me that you need to rethink your class hierarchy and maybie put some new superinterface or abstract class

Comment: myMap is a static class, so all instance of class A will have the same static map, how class A is not avaible to you? you just need an import class A;

Comment: Because class A is a subclass of class B and I'm using a class B container to store an instance of class A. When I refer to the class B container, it has it's own static HashMap which is not the correct one.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If I'm understanding you correctly, you want to use [reflection](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/reflect/index.html) to access the field. You can use [Class#getField](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getField%28java.lang.String%29) or [Class#getDeclaredField](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getDeclaredField%28java.lang.String%29) to access the map, like this:

```
Field hashmapField = clazz.getField("myMap");
//Note, since this is static, we pass it null.
Object fieldValue = hashmapField.get(null);
HashMap<String,String> myMap = (HashMap<String,String>)fieldValue;
```

However, if you have several classes that are going to have a "myMap" field, you may consider refactoring your code to have an [interface](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/concepts/interface.html) like this:

```
public interface StringMappable{
  HashMap<String,String> getMap();
}
```

instead of using reflection.

Comment: You can also pass it `clazz`, which I prefer, since the field belongs to the `Class` object

Comment: I still don't understand why he just do A.myMap

Comment: Well, in his code, if I'm understanding it right, `myfunction` is given a Class object that has a field called `myMap`. `myfunction` doesn't know that clazz is A; it might be some other class called B that has a static map, so he's trying to access `myMap` in a way independent of what clazz actually is.

Comment: Success. `getField` and then hashmapField.get(null) worked to get the specific static member I was in need of.

Comment: @Zach in this case, why don't use an interface?

Answer (score 3):

From: [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getField%28java.lang.String%29) and [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Field.html#get%28java.lang.Object%29):

```
clazz.getField("myMap").get(null)
```

Answer (score 2):

You want something like this:

```
public void myfunction(Class clazz)
{
    HashMap<String,String> myMap = clazz.getField("myMap").get(null);
}
```

The [`Field.get(Object)` method docs say](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Field.html#get%28java.lang.Object%29):

> If the underlying field is a static field, the obj argument is ignored; it may be null.

And the [`Class.getField(String)` method docs say](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getField%28java.lang.String%29):

> Returns a Field object that reflects the specified public member field of the class or interface represented by this Class object. The name parameter is a String specifying the simple name of the desired field.